# Fantasy novel where the character had to collect pendants

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I remember reading a fantasy novel as a teen, so it would have been a young-adult novel. In it the main character had to collect pendants to ward off an evil.

I remember him getting the first pendant early, and it had a cross type shape on it. I think perhaps a wizard granted him the first pendant so that the character would have the power to find the others. I don't think the character was granted any special powers, other than specific protection from an evil force.

I recall ravens and "cold" being themes... maybe a change in temperature and ravens signaled an imminent attack?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's probably [*The Dark is Rising*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Is_Rising_Sequence) by Susan Cooper.  It's the second book in the series.

> The main character of the second novel, and a major character in the entire series, [Will Stanton] is the seventh son of a seventh son, in a large, close human family. His eleventh birthday marks the beginning of his magical awakening and rise to power as the last of the Old Ones. The Dark Is Rising tells how he came to power, met Merriman Lyon, and accumulated the six "signs" to help fight the Dark. Will is the last of the Old Ones; no others will be born after him.

The Signs:

> A set of six circles quartered (divided evenly in four sections) by crosses. The six signs are each made of a different material and represent a different element: wood, bronze, iron, water, fire, and stone. The six Signs represent the Six champions of the Light, referred to in the recurring Poem of the Dark Is Rising series, as "three from the Circle, three from the Track". When used, the signs have the power to repel the Dark.

The whole book takes place in the winter, but the Dark also is tied to cold, as I recall.  Likewise:

> The rooks: The majority of these birds are servants of the Dark and attract their forces wherever they are seen.

There was a (loose) film adaptation in 2007 called [The Seeker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seeker_(film)).  There is a question [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31022/how-does-the-movie-the-seeker-the-dark-is-rising-compare-to-the-books-by-su) analyzing the differences.

---

It is a classic of YA fantasy and many people have read it (and asked about it).  Below is a link to a similar question.  I'm including it since it has links to other, related questions itself.

[Answered Question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22023/childrens-fantasy-series-with-a-symbol-consisting-of-a-circle-divided-into-quar/22025#22025)