# Movie: boy is coming of age to save the world, magical fight on a bridge

Tags: story-identification, movie

It's a little fuzzy, but I do remember some things. I remember there being a kid who had a brother, maybe his twin, and a blonde mother.

There is some kind of magic council of maybe 7 people who are trying to protect the world from a really bad guy. The main good guy is older, with an accent, and dark hair, maybe British, but he was not as old-looking as Gandalf. He finds and mentors the kid, and beyond that I think the kid saves the world and his brother in the process.

I remember something about some signs needing to occur. I also have a vague recollection of a magical fight on a bridge.

It's not *Spiderwick Chronicles* and it's not *Seventh Son*.

I first saw the movie via Amazon or SlingTV back in 2016 or so.

Comment: Hi. Please read [these suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/215541/edit) your question to add as much information as you can. For example: When did you see the movie?

Comment: The Seeker: The Dark is Rising?

Comment: @mkennedy I'll accept it as the answer, if you write it as an answer :)

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22023/childrens-fantasy-series-with-a-symbol-consisting-of-a-circle-divided-into-quar (about the series on which the film is based)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay! Going by British older mentor, young man he mentoring, a sibling, and some signs, I thought it sounded a bit like *The Dark is Rising* by Susan Cooper. I know they made a not-very-well-reviewed movie a few years ago that had changed the storyline. As it turned out, [The Seeker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seeker_(film)) is the movie decuser was looking for.

I can't give you details about the movie because I haven't seen it. But the main character is Will Stanton, the latest born of the Old Ones. People with powers who defend the Light against the Dark. His mentor is Merriman Lyon. The movie adapts the second book in the series, *The Dark is Rising* (also the name of the series). In it, Will has to gather six signs, like belt buckles. There's a poem that gives clues as well:

> “When the Dark comes rising six shall turn it back;
> Three from the circle, three from the track;
> Wood, bronze, iron; Water, fire, stone;
> Five will return and one go alone.
>
> Iron for the birthday; bronze carried long;
> Wood from the burning; stone out of song;
> Fire in the candle ring; water from the thaw;
> Six signs the circle and the grail gone before."

Comment: also: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31022/how-does-the-movie-the-seeker-the-dark-is-rising-compare-to-the-books-by-su/31039#31039